# How to find HTML tags with certain text? - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

Here's the source:

```
<span class="new"> <a class="blog" href="http://whatever1.com" rel="nofollow">whatever1</a> do something at <a class="others" href="http://example1.com" rel="nofollow">example1</a></span>

<span class="new"> <a class="blog" href="http://whatever2.com" rel="nofollow">whatever2</a> do other things at <a class="others" href="http://example2.com" rel="nofollow">example2</a></span>

<span class="new"> <a class="blog" href="http://whatever3.com" rel="nofollow">whatever3</a> do something at <a class="others" href="http://example3.com" rel="nofollow">example3</a></span>
```

I want to find all `<span class="new">` with `do something at` in it, and here's my code, I just don't know why it's not working:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
all_tags = soup.findAll(name = "span", attrs = {"class": "new"}, text = re.compile('do something.*'))
```

Nothing found. If I remove `text = re.compile('.*do something.*')` all above tags can be found, I know there should be something wrong with my regex pattern, so what is the correct form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always try a hybrid approach:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
spans = soup.findAll("span", attrs = {"class": "new"})
regex = re.compile('.*do something at.*')
desired_tags = [span for span in spans if regex.match(span.text)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work. What i don't understand is, how come it does NOT work when you combine all above in one line like this: `spans = soup.findAll("span", attrs = {"class": "new"}, text = re.compile('.*do something at.*'))`

Comment: My guess is that `text=` only works for tags that have text but not other tags. In your HTML each `<span>` has `<a>` tags mixed in with the text. If the span didn't have child tags I think it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

iterate over the html file content and print the lines that match. Here I replaced the file content with the list l :

```
>>> l = ['<span class="new"> <a class="blog" href="http://whatever1.com" rel="nofollow">whatever1</a> do something at <a class="others" href="http://example1.com" rel="nofollow">example1</a></span>', 

'<span class="new"> <a class="blog" href="http://whatever2.com" rel="nofollow">whatever2</a> do other things at <a class="others" href="http://example2.com" rel="nofollow">example2</a></span>',

'<span class="new"> <a class="blog" href="http://whatever3.com" rel="nofollow">whatever3</a> do something at <a class="others" href="http://example3.com" rel="nofollow">example3</a></span>' ]
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
    if re.search('<span class="new">.*do something.*', l[i]):
        print l[i]


<span class="new"> <a class="blog" href="http://whatever1.com" rel="nofollow">whatever1</a> do something at <a class="others" href="http://example1.com" rel="nofollow">example1</a></span>
<span class="new"> <a class="blog" href="http://whatever3.com" rel="nofollow">whatever3</a> do something at <a class="others" href="http://example3.com" rel="nofollow">example3</a></span>
>>>
```

Comment: this definitely works, but the problem is, i need to parse the selected tags, grab urls and similar. BeautifulSoup would do a better job for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I normally find text.

```
spans = soup.findAll("span", attrs = {"class": "new"})
for s in spans:
    if "do something" in str(s):
```